# iTunes unable to backup data before iOS upgrade

Tags: iphone

After uploading iOS 5 to my iPhone, there was a message from iTunes saying that, during the procedure, iTunes was unable to backup my data. So nothing got restored and I lost a great number of photos and other stuff with no further explanation. Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: Check if iTunes has *some* backup, then use it explicitly to restore the phone.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error on my iPhone 4 iOS 5 upgrade.  But mine specifically said if I proceed despite the error, all content would be lost.  Did you proceed past this error?

Check your iTunes Edit > Preferences > Devices and see if you have more than 1 backup listed.  Mine has 2, my current backup and my last iOS 4 backup.